# error while using apt-get install for any package

Tags: apt, dpkg

I have tried to install texlive-full with `apt-get` and the installation stopped due to some errors. Later I removed all folders and files related to texlive, texmf manually. Since then I get the following error while trying to use apt-get install for any package. I have tried `apt-get clean`, `aptitude clean` etc. Can someone please help me. I think it is the `dpkg` which is giving the errors.

I'm using Linux Mint and am new to using Linux. I have pasted the error message below:

```
Setting up tex-common (3.13) ...
find: `/etc/texmf/texmf.d': No such file or directory
update-language-dat: cannot read /etc/texmf/hyphen.d/00tex.cnf
update-language-dat: if it was removed by accident, it has to be reinstalled with
update-language-dat:   t=$(mktemp -d); cd $t; apt-get download tex-common ; dpkg -i --force-confmiss tex-common*.deb
dpkg: error processing tex-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latex-sanskrit:
 latex-sanskrit depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing latex-sanskrit (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of tex-gyre:
 tex-gyre depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing tex-gyre (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-latex-base:
 texlive-latex-base depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing texlive-latex-base (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of asymptote:
 asymptote depends on texlive-latex-base; however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.
 asymptote depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing asymptote (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of context:
 context depends on tex-gyre; however:
  Package tex-gyre is not configured yet.
 context depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing context (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of context-modules:
 context-modules depends on context (>> 2011); however:
  Package context is not configured yet.
 context-modules depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing context-modules (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ipe:
 ipe depends on texlive-latex-base; however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing ipe (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-latex-recommended:
 texlive-latex-recommended depends on texlive-latex-base (>= 2012.20120516); however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.
 texlive-latex-recommended depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing texlive-latex-recommended (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latex-xcolor:
 latex-xcolor depends on texlive-latex-recommended; however:
  Package texlive-latex-recommended is not configured yet.
 latex-xcolor depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing latex-xcolor (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of pgf:
 pgf depends on tex-common (>= 2.00); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.
 pgf depends on texlive-latex-recommended; however:
  Package texlive-latex-recommended is not configured yet.
 pgf depends on latex-xcolor (>= 2.00-1); however:
  Package latex-xcolor is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing pgf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latex-beamer:
 latex-beamer depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.
 latex-beamer depends on pgf (>= 1.00-1); however:
  Package pgf is not configured yet.
 latex-beamer depends on latex-xcolor (>= 2.00-1); however:
  Package latex-xcolor is not configured yet.
 latex-beamer depends on texlive-latex-base; however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing latex-beamer (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-bkai00mp:
 latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-bkai00mp depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-bkai00mp (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-bsmi00lp:
 latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-bsmi00lp depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-bsmi00lp (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-gbsn00lp:
 latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-gbsn00lp depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-gbsn00lp (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-gkai00mp:
 latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-gkai00mp depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-gkai00mp (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latex-cjk-japanese-wadalab:
 latex-cjk-japanese-wadalab depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing latex-cjk-japanese-wadalab (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up m-tx (0.60d-5) ...
warning: kpathsea: configuration file texmf.cnf not found in these directories: /etc/texmf/web2c:/usr/share/texlive/texmf/web2c:/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c:/usr/local/share/texmf/web2c.
/var/lib/dpkg/info/m-tx.postinst: 17: /var/lib/dpkg/info/m-tx.postinst: $TEXMFMAIN/web2c/mktexupd: not found
dpkg: error processing m-tx (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of musixtex:
 musixtex depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing musixtex (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of prosper:
 prosper depends on texlive-latex-base; however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.
 prosper depends on texlive-latex-recommended; however:
  Package texlive-latex-recommended is not configured yet.
 prosper depends on tex-common (>= 1.10); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing prosper (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-doc-ar:
 texlive-doc-ar depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing texlive-doc-ar (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-doc-bg:
 texlive-doc-bg depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing texlive-doc-bg (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-doc-cs+sk:
 texlive-doc-cs+sk depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing texlive-doc-cs+sk (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-doc-de:
 texlive-doc-de depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing texlive-doc-de (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-doc-en:
 texlive-doc-en depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing texlive-doc-en (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-doc-es:
 texlive-doc-es depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing texlive-doc-es (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-doc-fi:
 texlive-doc-fi depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing texlive-doc-fi (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-doc-fr:
 texlive-doc-fr depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing texlive-doc-fr (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-doc-it:
 texlive-doc-it depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing texlive-doc-it (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-doc-ja:
 texlive-doc-ja depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing texlive-doc-ja (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-doc-ko:
 texlive-doc-ko depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing texlive-doc-ko (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-doc-mn:
 texlive-doc-mn depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing texlive-doc-mn (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-doc-nl:
 texlive-doc-nl depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing texlive-doc-nl (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-doc-pl:
 texlive-doc-pl depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing texlive-doc-pl (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-doc-pt:
 texlive-doc-pt depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing texlive-doc-pt (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-doc-rs:
 texlive-doc-rs depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing texlive-doc-rs (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-doc-ru:
 texlive-doc-ru depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing texlive-doc-ru (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-doc-si:
 texlive-doc-si depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing texlive-doc-si (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-doc-th:
 texlive-doc-th depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing texlive-doc-th (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-doc-tr:
 texlive-doc-tr depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing texlive-doc-tr (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-doc-uk:
 texlive-doc-uk depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing texlive-doc-uk (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-doc-vi:
 texlive-doc-vi depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing texlive-doc-vi (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-doc-zh:
 texlive-doc-zh depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing texlive-doc-zh (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-fonts-extra:
 texlive-fonts-extra depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing texlive-fonts-extra (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-fonts-extra-doc:
 texlive-fonts-extra-doc depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing texlive-fonts-extra-doc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-fonts-recommended:
 texlive-fonts-recommended depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing texlive-fonts-recommended (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-fonts-recommended-doc:
 texlive-fonts-recommended-doc depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing texlive-fonts-recommended-doc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-generic-extra:
 texlive-generic-extra depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing texlive-generic-extra (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-humanities-doc:
 texlive-humanities-doc depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing texlive-humanities-doc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-lang-african:
 texlive-lang-african depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing texlive-lang-african (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-lang-arabic:
 texlive-lang-arabic depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing texlive-lang-arabic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 tex-common
 latex-sanskrit
 tex-gyre
 texlive-latex-base
 asymptote
 context
 context-modules
 ipe
 texlive-latex-recommended
 latex-xcolor
 pgf
 latex-beamer
 latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-bkai00mp
 latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-bsmi00lp
 latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-gbsn00lp
 latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-gkai00mp
 latex-cjk-japanese-wadalab
 m-tx
 musixtex
 prosper
 texlive-doc-ar
 texlive-doc-bg
 texlive-doc-cs+sk
 texlive-doc-de
 texlive-doc-en
 texlive-doc-es
 texlive-doc-fi
 texlive-doc-fr
 texlive-doc-it
 texlive-doc-ja
 texlive-doc-ko
 texlive-doc-mn
 texlive-doc-nl
 texlive-doc-pl
 texlive-doc-pt
 texlive-doc-rs
 texlive-doc-ru
 texlive-doc-si
 texlive-doc-th
 texlive-doc-tr
 texlive-doc-uk
 texlive-doc-vi
 texlive-doc-zh
 texlive-fonts-extra
 texlive-fonts-extra-doc
 texlive-fonts-recommended
 texlive-fonts-recommended-doc
 texlive-generic-extra
 texlive-humanities-doc
 texlive-lang-african
 texlive-lang-arabic
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: "I manually removed" sounds like the time when you messed up to the point where we cannot really help you.  I'd love to be proven wrong but this is a recurring anti-pattern which forces us to abandon many reasonable assumptions about how your system is working.

Comment: Luckily the diagnostics suggest some things to try.  Have you tried them?

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same problem. Did you solve this?

Answer (score 4):

> I removed all folders and files related to texlive, texmf manually

Ouch.

You can try reinstalling these packages. You'll need to force things along. Start by downloading the packages:

```
apt-get -d --reinstall install texlive texlive-common …
```

You'll have to list all the packages you messed up. Then unpack them with `dpkg`.

```
dpkg --unpack /var/cache/apt/archives/texlive*
```

Then try configuring them all:

```
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get -f install
```

It's hard to predict whether this will work. If it doesn't work, remove the affected packages and then install them again. You'll have to remove the pre- and post-removal scripts as they're likely to fail.

```
rm /var/lib/dpkg/texlive*.post*
dpkg -r texlive-common texlive …
apt-get -f install
apt-get install texlive
```

Answer (score 1):

I am a little late to the party but I just had this issue, and this solved it for me:

I tried to uninstall one of the packages and that seemed to make things worse. So I tried reinstalling but was blocked by this issue in the original post, so after much hunting I discovered this related to an issue I caused by removing one of the packages.

```
sudo -s
cd /var/cache/debconf
rm *.dat
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

After that everything seemed to be working fine and this issue was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

A similar problem happened to me after 3 months without updating my system, for the record:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Linuxmint
Description:    Linux Mint 20.1
Release:    20.1
Codename:   ulyssa
```

However, in my case, I had not removed anything manually and I don't recall doing anything drastic.  The errors I got upon trying `apt upgrade` were:

```
dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386:
 libglib2.0-0:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.28); however:
  Package libc6:i386 is not configured yet.
 libglib2.0-0:i386 depends on libmount1 (>= 2.28); however:
  Package libmount1:i386 is not configured yet.
 libglib2.0-0:i386 depends on zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.2); however:
  Package zlib1g:i386 is not configured yet.
```

In any case, these are the steps that I followed to recover the situation and, so far, it appears to have worked:

```
$ sudo apt remove zlib1g:i386 libmount1:i386 libc6:i386 libglib2.0-0:i386
```

This generated an impressive list of additional libraries and applications removed containing no less than 264 entries.  I copied the entire console output to a file named packages_removed.txt and then did the following:

```
$ grep Removing packages_removed.txt | cut -d' ' -f2 > removed.txt
$ sudo apt install zlib1g:i386 libmount1:i386 libc6:i386 libglib2.0-0:i386
$ sudo apt autoremove --yes
$ xargs -n 1 -a removed.txt sudo apt install --yes
$ sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade --yes
```

The last command, unsurprisingly, resulted in no further changes to the system.